# Use two variables, one for mysql_query and another for mysql_fetch_array. Is that fair?

Tags: php, mysql

I always use two variables to show the content of a column from a table. My table is "a_table" and has just one column called "name" (varchar). I'm doing it well?

```
<?php

//Just junk 
$connect =  mysql_connect('localhost', 'root');
if (!$enlace) {
    die('DAMN: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'GREAT';

$connect =  mysql_select_db('my_db', $connect);
if (!$enlace) {
    die('DAMN: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'GREAT X2';

//Important 

$name = mysql_query('SELECT `a_column` FROM `a_table`.`my_db` LIMIT 0, 30');
if (!$name) {
    die('DAMN' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'GREAT';

// Every mysql_query gives me a RESOURCE, so I've used to apply mysql_fetch_array

$the_variable_that_put_the_name_on_screen = mysql_fetch_array($name); 

echo  $the_variable_that_put_the_name_on_screen['name'];

function closeConn(){
    mysql_close();
}

?>
```

Comment: What do you mean well? What's the problem you are having?

Comment: Well = Correctly (at least for me, hahaha) :D

I'm not having any problem. I just want to know if it's correct.

'cause I think that using two variables to show the content is not a great deal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have written above is ok.

Although FYI mysql functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0.
If you are just learning it would be a good time to learn another database extensive like mysqli or PDO.

Ref: http://nz1.php.net/mysql_fetch_array